# Django object creation from form with nested elements - not behaving as expected

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using Django 3.2

I am trying to create an object that has child elements, (without using formsets). I have used Javascipt to build a user friendly UI that allows a user to dynamically add the child elements.

The post method of the route handler class parses the POST fields and extracts the child elements.

This is a simplified version of my codebase:

#### /path/to/myapp/models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    start_date = models.DateTime()
    end_date = models.DateTime()


class Choice(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    pos = models.PositiveSmallInteger(default=0)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CACSCADE, related_name='choices')
```

#### /path/to/myapp/forms.py

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        start_date = cleaned_data['start_date']
        end_date = cleaned_data['end_date']

        if end_date <= start_date:
            self.add_error('end_date', ValidationError(_('End date must be greater than the start date'), code=_('invalid_date')))
         

    class Meta:
        model = Question
```

#### /path/to/myapp/views.py

```
class QuestionCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Question
    form_class = QuestionForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post_data = request.POST

        question_choice_data = [x.split('-') for x in post_data.get('question_choices','').split(',')]  # <- object is sometimes created on this line!

        form = self.form_class(post_data)
   
        if form.is_valid():
            new_question = form.save(commit=False)    

            # set some field attributes 
            # ...

            new_question.save()       

            for position, choice_name in question_choice_data:
                Choice.objects.create(question=new_question, title=choice_name, pos=int(position))
```

When I attempt to save a new question by POSTing, two unexpected things happen:

1. The `post()` method appears to be being called is called twice
2. the Question object is getting created before the form.is_valid() method call

Why is this happening, and how do I rectify this?